# Expo InAppPurchases Error: Must be connected to App Store

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am using Expo In App Purchases and I am getting “Error: Must be connected to App Store” error on android device even though I have made the necessary settings in the play store. I am only developing android app and I will not use ios app. I published my app as a closed test on the Play store and created a subscription.